# How Guess Which Fonts Are Used In Corel Draw File Without Using CorelDraw or Macro

Tags: vba, coreldraw

How Guess Which Fonts Are Used In Corel Draw File Without Using CorelDraw or Macro. I mean any hack using binary codes or enyhing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corel Draw File Is Nothing But A Zip File Any File Using Notepad Or Other Text Editor. If Any File Starts With PK then it is zip file :) Just extract it and you will find text.xml there is all info about your cdr :)